# Problemas com $http e ng-repeat angularjs iniciante $$hashKey

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

Olá sou iniciante no Angular e estou achando muito bacana, meu problema é o seguinte:

tenho um ng-repeat que funciona direitinho quando pego a fonte de dados de uma variável javascript assim:

```
var alertsq = [  
{  
    "alert":"mediun",
    "nt":"28",
    "nu":"28",
    "no":"34",
    "dtini":"2012/Jul/23",
    "no":"3",
    "dtoc":"23/7/2012",
    "dtuo":"25/7/2012",
    "id":"227529436529033216",
    "msg":"Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room: http://t.co/n56emZf2"
},
{  
    "alert":"mediun",
    "nt":"28",
    "nu":"28",
    "no":"34",
    "dtini":"2012/Jul/23",
    "no":"3",
    "dtoc":"23/7/2012",
    "dtuo":"25/7/2012",
    "id":"227529436529033216",
    "msg":"Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room: http://t.co/n56emZf2"
}];
```

Meu controller que pega a variável *alertsq* e seta no escopo é assim:

```
app.controller("alertsController", function(){    
    console.log(alertsq);
    this.alerts = alertsq;
});
```

O bacana é que isso funciona e minha lista no `*ng-repeat*` é preenchida lindamente, mas quando utilizo o *$http* para carregar um conteúdo JSON de um arquivo o mesmo não preenche a lista: ó código do controller é assim:

```
app.controller("alertsController", function($http,$scope){    
    $http({
        url: "data/alerts.json",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        } 
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.alerts = data;
        console.log($scope.alerts);
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

O legal é que o JSON esta vindo certinho a saída do navegador no primeiro caso em
que a lista é preenchida é assim:

```
mainController controller.js:7

 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
     0: Object
     $$hashKey:"object:4" 
     alert: "mediun"
     dtini: "2012/Jul/23"
     dtoc: "23/7/2012"    
     dtuo: "25/7/2012"
     id: "227529436529033216"
     msg: "Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the              
     door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room:       
     http://t.co/n56emZf2"
     no:"3"    
     nt: "28"
     nu: "28"__proto__: 
    Object1: 
    Object2:
```

E esta é a saída do console quando busco por $http o JSON:

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 0: Object 
 alert: "mediun"
 dtini: "2012/Jul/23"
 dtoc: "23/7/2012"    
 dtuo: "25/7/2012"
 id: "227529436529033216"
 msg: "Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the              
 door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room:       
 http://t.co/n56emZf2"
 no:"3"    
 nt: "28"
 nu: "28"__proto__: 
Object1: 
Object2:
```

O detalhe é que na saída obtida pelo JSON através do $http não existe o atributo  $$hashKey, E assim a lista no ng-repeat não é preenchida :(, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso?

Agradeço a atenção!

Comment: A requisição do json está ok, provavelmente o erro está na iteração com o html. Veja seu código rodando normalmente http://plnkr.co/edit/Y36tkeVAIPEFp22WnLqi?p=preview

Comment: Olá a solução para o meu problema aqui:
[Problemas com ng-repeat][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390959/dificult-reading-json-and-add-ng-repeat-list-list-is-not-completed-http-has/27393640#27393640

Comment: Faltou colocar o html do ng-repeat

Comment: Se você postar o seu HTML já ajudaria... pois o problema como citado, é seu HTML não sua requisição http, nem controller, nem nada...

Comment: @WagnerMonteverde Então responda você mesmo com o link pro SOEn, mas traduza os parágrafos da resposta pra que ela não seja sinalizada como "apenas um link"

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tive problemas com json trazendo objetos javascript, ng-repeat não consegue trabalhar com objetos, tive que usar um filter object2Array.

```
ng-repeat="item in items | object2Array "

minhaApp.filter('object2Array', function(){
    return function(input){
        return angular.fromJson(input);//out;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos la, coisas que achei estranhas:

```
}).success(function(data){
        $scope.alerts = data;
        console.log($scope.alerts);
    }
```

Você esta retornando um JSON logo o formato padrão de chegada dele é:

```
{index:valor}
```

Na atribuição esse `data`que você esta atribuindo ao `$scope.alerts` deveria ser um `data.index`, por que realmente o data ta te retornando um conjunto de objetos e não um arrayList

Bom, não sei se esse pode ser o erro, mas se quiser tentar fica dica :D

OBS: Em vez de configurar $http use ja os pré definidos pelo próprio angular! Exemplo:

```
$http.get('linkdarequisição')
    .success(function(data){
       //codigo
    })
```